# Animating two different styled texts using Textillate

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am trying to use Textillate to animate three differently styled texts. The texts need to animate at the same speed. Both node and node2 are the same text, just styled differently, with one overlaid on the other.

I need node and node2 to animate at the same speed. The characters animate separately, and as both texts are the same character length, that is working properly.

However, I need the two spans of node2 to be styled differently. However, the span tags are ignored and they are being styled according to the class indicated in the Textilate function.

Is there any way to apply different styles to the two spans of node2?

Codepen is here: https://codepen.io/sachisasachi/pen/RVmgpw

```
var node, node2, len;


$('.hbstart').click(function() {
$('.hbstart').remove();

for(var i=0, len=<? echo count($words)?>; i < len; i++){
<?

$i=0;
foreach($words as $word){
?>

node = document.createElement("LI");                        
node.innerHTML = "TEXT <?=$word['word']?>";
document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node); 

node2 = document.createElement("LI");                       
node2.innerHTML = "<span class='comp'><?=$word['compspace']?></span>
<span class='comp2'><?=$word['comp']?></span>";
document.getElementById("myList2").appendChild(node2); 

<? }
$i++;?>

}


$('.tlt, .tlt2').textillate({
 selector: '.texts',
 loop: true,
 minDisplayTime: 2000,  
 initialDelay: 0,   
 autoStart: true,
 inEffects: [], 
 outEffects: [],

 in: {
  effect: 'fadeIn', 
  delayScale: 1.5, 
  delay: 50,
  sync: false, 
  shuffle: true,
  reverse: false,
  callback: function () {}
 },

 out: {
  effect: 'fadeOut',
  delayScale: 1.5,
  delay: 50,
  sync: false,
  shuffle: true,
  reverse: false,
 callback: function () {}
 },
 callback: function () {}
  type: 'char',
});
```

and my HTML is:

```
 <h1 class="tlt">
  <ul class="texts" id="myList">
  <li class="hbstart">HB</li>
  </ul> 
 </h1>

 <h1 class="tlt2">
  <ul class="texts" id="myList2">
  </ul>
 </h1>
```

Comment: Can you create a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or a [codePen](https://codepen.io/) ?

Comment: https://codepen.io/sachisasachi/pen/RVmgpw

Comment: Okay... And what do you want to change in style... For example?

Comment: I want the .comp class to be transparent and the .comp2 class to be white.

Comment: From what I can see... Classes `.comp` and `.comp2` always are at `display:none` due to their parent `ul` which only serve as a "word bank" to what really is displayed. Have a look at this [code inspector printscreen](http://imgur.com/JZaZmGp). Sorry, but it is a no can do just with simple CSS. You'll have to do deep tweaks on th JS do achieve what you want.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks a lot for helping me see what was going on! Any idea of how I could tweak the JS?

Comment: No I don't... It looks like having to re-ingineer the whole thing.